# How to invoke Privoxy?

Tags: internet, proxy, port, privoxy

I have installed Privoxy on Windows 7 64-bit and by searching through it's docs I have found that i need to enter some command line arguments to install the Privoxy service. Now, where and how do I have to enter command line arguments?

Here is the installation note on official Privoxy docs:

Just double-click the installer, which will guide you through the installation process. You will find the configuration files in the same directory as you installed Privoxy in.
Version 3.0.5 beta introduced full Windows service functionality. On Windows only, the Privoxy program has two new command line arguments to install and uninstall Privoxy as a service.
Arguments:
--install[:service_name]
--uninstall[:service_name]
After invoking Privoxy with --install, you will need to bring up the Windows service console to assign the user you want Privoxy to run under, and whether or not you want it to run whenever the system starts. You can start the Windows services console with the following command: services.msc. If you do not take the manual step of modifying Privoxy's service settings, it will not start. Note too that you will need to give Privoxy a user account that actually exists, or it will not be permitted to write to its log and configuration files.

Comment: Open a command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I run Privoxy?

- `Start` -> `Run` -> `cmd`
- `cd /d <privoxy installation directory>`
- `privoxy --install`

Note:

Privoxy does not have to be installed as a service.